# MVC - Ajax.BeginForm() generating empty action

Tags: asp.net-mvc, http-post, asp.net-mvc-routing, html.beginform

Current page URL: http://localhost:25265/SearchResultsList.aspx

view looks like:

```
@using (Html.BeginForm("RefineSearchResults", "Search", FormMethod.Post, new {id = "myForm"}))
{
 <input type="submit" value="submit" />
}
```

Routes:

```
routes.MapRoute(
                "Search",
                "SearchResultsList.aspx",
                new { controller = "Search", action = "SearchResults" }
            );


routes.MapRoute(
                name: "Default",
                url: "{controller}/{action}",
                defaults: new { controller = "Home", action = "Index"},
                namespaces: new[] { "MyApp.WebUI.Controllers" }
            );
```

But, I noticed that it's generating empty action.
looks like:

```
<form action method="post">
<input type="submit" value="submit"> </form>
```

Can anyone please tell me what's this happening? Where I'm doing wrong!!

Comment: try and pass the form name manually and also reverse the order of  the routes

Comment: I tried as you said but, didn't helped!

Comment: you tried both the things?

Comment: Yes. I have updated my question accordingly.

Comment: It works when I add the form tag manually (without using html helper) with desired action like this: <form action="controler/action" method="post">